# 'HttpModule' is deprecated

Tags: javascript, angular

Can someone explain why the 'HttpModule' is crossed out?

I tried to follow the structure program of my instructor because I'm coding along with him. I must have missed something but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Do you mean `@angular/http`? That's been deprecated since v4.3 (for five and a half years!) in favour of `@angular/common/http`. I think it was removed entirely in v9. Use up-to-date learning resources.

Comment: It was removed in v8, itself nearly four years old: https://v8.angular.io/guide/deprecations#removed-apis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually the Http module that you are using is officially deprecated and hence it is crossed out

You will have to use a newer HttpClientModule instead

It's an upgraded version of http from @angular/http module

Comment: The system said I need 15 reputations to upvote. I'm still new here.